# Why does this keep reading null rather than setting my div to different id's

Tags: javascript, html, css

So basically we're trying to make a pixel art program where you assign "pixels" to different div colors. I keep returning id's rather than resetting them, even if they're null. We're supposed to be doing this in vanilla javascript even though jQuery would make it significantly easier

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

  console.log("dom content loaded");
    //sets up div for loop.

  function divAdder() {
    var pixelContainer = document.createElement("div");
    pixelContainer.setAttribute("class", "pixelContainer");
    document.body.appendChild(pixelContainer);

      //creates and numbers divs
    for (var i = 0; i < 1073; i++) {

      var id = "Div ID #";
      var element = document.createElement("div");

      element.setAttribute("class", "pixelClass");
      document.addEventListener("click",colorPicker);
      document.addEventListener("click",colorSet);
      pixelContainer.appendChild(element);

    }
  }
divAdder()

var currentColor = undefined
  function colorPicker(event) {
      currentColor = event.target.getAttribute("id")
      console.log("currentColor = " + currentColor)
  }

  function colorSet(event){
    console.log( "colorSet = " + currentColor)
    event.target.setAttribute("id", currentColor)

  };
```

Comment: What is expected result of `colorSet` function?

Answer (score 0):

At JavaScript at Question the event is attached to `document`, not the created element `element`. `event.target` within `click` handler is `document`, not `element`.  No `id` is set at `element`. Note also `id` of element in `document` should be unique.

Comment: Thanks! I was super close and this got me there